# Why not @Valid trigger the validation with hibernate validator ?

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-boot

I am trying to validate a incoming Json request when it is getting bind in Spring Boot controller with `Hibernate- validator`. Here is my simple Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ValidationTestApplication {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidationTestApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ValidationTestApplication.class, args);
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Node> postController(@Valid @RequestBody Node node, BindingResult result) {
    logger.info("Hit in post controller");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.error("Found Error !!!!");
        result.getAllErrors().forEach(i -> logger.error(i.toString()));
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(node);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(node);
}
static class Node {

    @NotBlank
    String name;
    int age;
    // ... default, all args constructor
    // ... getters and setters. 

}
}
```

I have mark the `name` property `NotBlank` so that I am accepting that if blank value assign in `name` field I will get bad request response.

Here is the Json with that I am testing

```
{
  "name":"",
  "age":23
}
```

But I am not getting any error. I suppose it is not triggering the validation whatsoever. What part I am missing here ?

I have also provide my `POM` if you find it is useful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.seal</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>validation-test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-maven -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Try to make the class `Node` a top-level class. Currently it's static inner class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this dependency to `pom.xml`.